# Identify the person referred to in an email using ML/NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, word2vec

I am working on an NLP project, wherein I have a list of emails all related to appreciation. I am trying to determine from the email content, who is being appreciated. This in turn will help the organization in our performance evaluation program.

Apart from identifying who is being appreciated, I am also trying to identify the type of work a person has done and score it. I am using open NLP (max entropy/logistic regression) for classification of the email and use some form of heuristics to identify the person being appreciated.

The approach for person identification is as follows:

1. Determine if an email is related to appreciation
2. Get the list of people in the "To:" list
3. Check if that person is being referred to in the email
4. Tag that person as the receiver of appreciation

However, this approach is very simple and does not work for complex emails we generally see. An email can consist of many email ids or people being referred to and they are not the receivers of the appreciation. The context of the person is not available and hence the accuracy is not very good.

I am thinking of using HMM and word2vec to solve the person issue. I would appreciate if anyone has come across this problem or has any suggestion.

Comment: You should give a samples of your text.

Answer (score 0):

Use tm package for R. And use tf-idf (term frequency - inverse document frequency) to determine whos been appreciate.

I'm suggesting this because , for what I can read , this is an unsupervised learning (you dont knot prior whos been appreciate). So you have to describe the documents (emails) content , and that formula (tf-idf) will help know what words are been use most in a particular document that are rarely uso on all anothers.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is through the use of Named Entity Recognition. You can possibly run something like Stanford NER over the text which will help you recognize all people names mentioned in the email and then use a rules based chunker such as Stanford TokensRegex to extract sentences where names of people and appreciation words are mentioned.

The best way to solve this will be by treating this as a supervised learning problem. You will then need to annotate a bunch of training data with entities and expression phrases and the relations between them. Then you can use Stanford Relation Extractor to extract appropriate relations.